# Reserve Memory For Shell / Putty To Login When Server Is Overloaded (High Load)

Tags: failover, high-load

I am currently trying to improve my failover strategies. Aside from adding a DNS failover I want to make sure I am able to log in via a shell

Whenever the server is overloaded I am unable to log in or at least it takes 20 minutes - 60 minutes until I can stop the service that is overloading the service

Of course the best strategy is to avoid overloads in the first place, however it would be nice to know if there is a way to reserve resources for a shell or a script

Any suggestions for failover / emergency situations are appreciated

Cheers

Comment: This is one of the many reasons you need out-of-band management for your servers - the ability to sign in using the **real** console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern linuxes you can use [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) to reserve certain system resources and/or limit applications so the don't use all resources.